# Migration VC++ MFC V6 to V2013: Toolbar color doesn't use visual styles

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc, migration, toolbar

I have an issue with my toolbar in a Visual Studio C++ MFC projcet that has been migrated from version 6 to version 2013.

I had to use manifest to enable visual styles which works fine now, besides the toolbar (CToolbar). If I change the windows 7 style to classic, it all looks fine. If I change the style to usual windows (no matter if with or without aero), it looks little weird: The backgound color displays a static light gray, whereas the dividor/separator is in silver color.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem (background color of icon toolbar = silver or dividor/separator = light gray)? Thanks in advance!!